# Datasource instanciation error with actuator

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using **Spring Boot 2.0.6.RELEASE**. My application uses the **Oracle jdbc driver** and works nice with this kind of configuration:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@my-data-server/database
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=pwd
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

But... **When adding actuator, the application fails to start**. It seems that the `/health` endpoint causes this problem (maybe because it is the first bean which needs a datasource?).

The problem is that the datasource can't be instanciate... But it works well without actuator.

Any idea ?

I was wondering if `DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration` **could be the source of the problem**: this class has the anotation `@AutoConfigureAfter(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)`... But it seems that Hikari doesn't use this autoconfig class, does it? I see `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari` in the stack trace but not `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`...

**UPDATE : ** I'm using FlyWay

**UPDATE 2 **, This may be a hint: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14687

---

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
2019-02-08 17:33:38.359 ERROR 14652 --- [ost-startStop-1] 
o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
    Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
    Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]: Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
    Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8065d973]: Constructor threw exception; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
    Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; 
nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

2019-02-08 17:33:38.381  INFO 14652 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-02-08 17:33:38.416  WARN 14652 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [spring.cloud.inetutils] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-02-08 17:33:38.419  WARN 14652 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2019-02-08 17:33:38.437  INFO 14652 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-02-08 17:33:38.445 ERROR 14652 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (the profiles dev are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: The bean being called `scopedTarget.dataSource` suggests that it's being proxied by something. Can you share some more details about your application, ideally a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve)

Comment: It may be Flyway, I've forgotten to mention it. I don't manage to create a sample applicaiton that reproduce it :/